# Oracle procedure to increase salary with parameter

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper, procedure

I am trying to solve this problem since 2 days and I think I am going crazy. I think there is a simple way but I couldn't see that.

First of all here are my tables:

- PERSONNEL (P_ID, P_NAME, P_SURNAME, BIRTH_DATE, DEPT_CODE)
- PERSONNEL_SPECIAL (P_ID, SALARY)
- PERSONNEL_ATTENDANCE (ID, P_ID, A_DATE, A_TIME, STATUS)
- DEPARTMENT (DEPT_CODE, DEPT_NAME, EDUCATION_TYPE, FACULTY_CODE)
- FACULTY (FACULTY_CODE, FACULTY_NAME)

I want to write a procedure which increases the salaries of personnel exist in faculty given as parameter. The parameter is faculty_code.

If you can help me I would be thankful to you. I don't know maybe my brain is too tired that's why I can't find the solution. Thank you anyway

Comment: It would improve your question if you could post your attempts, so that people can edit/complete what you've done.

Comment: Please show what you have attempted, and read [ask].  So is not a "do my homework" service.

Answer (score 0):

Would something like this work?

```
create or replace procedure p_inc_sal (
   par_faculty_code   in faculty.faculty_code%type,
   par_pct_inc        in number)
is
begin
   update personnel_special ps
      set ps.salary = ps.salary * (1 + par_pct_inc / 100)
    where exists
             (select null
                from personnel p
                     join department d on d.dept_code = p.dept_code
               where     d.faculty_code = par_faculty_code
                     and p.p_id = ps.p_id);
end;
```